# Fixing WooCommerce/Wordpress PHP Error Message

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

any help fixing this issue would be appreciated. I get this error message on my WP website:

```
function custom_product_description( $atts ) {
    global $product;

    try {
        if ( is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) ) {
            return wc_format_content( $product->get_description( 'shortcode' ) );
        }
        
        return 'Product description shortcode run outside of product context';
    } catch ( Exception $e ) {
        return 'Product description shortcode encountered an exception';
    }
}
add_shortcode( 'custom_product_description', 'custom_product_description' );
```

Craig

Some sort of custom field error message to do with WC products

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say where you put this shortcode. If you are adding this shortcode inside the product description, then you will get an infinite loop. Shortcode will get the description with the same shortcode and execute it.
Try replacing `$product->get_description( 'shortcode' )` with some static text.
What are you trying to do with this function?